# Blank browser after clearing the cache

Tags: caching, wsod

I migrated a site from windows xampp to ubuntu. It was working fine. But once I cleared the cache, the browser is showing blank screen.I tried going to different urls . I also tried clean urls but nothing is coming. All I can see is a white/blank browser.

Comment: i guess your ubuntu is a local environment without any access limitations, additionally suggest that you check the php error log for any quick hints of code level errors (ensuring that error reporting is on and set to a preferred level...)

Comment: check the logs, they usually point to the problem, on ubuntu check your apache and syslogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The White Screen of Death (Completely Blank Page)](http://drupal.org/node/158043) is a good starting point to takle down the problem.

For D7, **extension=php_domxml.dll** in php.ini must be commented out. With that dll enabled, I got a blank screen too in Windows.
Check with your php configuration in your linux server.

Comment: the given link worked for me . I just had to make some changes in index.php. I added this in index.php.                                                                                          <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

Comment: What did you see the error on your screen after you enabled error reporting?

Comment: The error was regarding a module that I was not even using anymore. So I deleted that module and everything worked fine.

Comment: Then, you may need to retag because I think the tag "caching" is not directly related with this subject.